# prices by calendar

Tags: php, mysql, sql

We want to create a job system that allows providers to specify different prices based on time. So on M-F from 9-5pm, they might charge $10 for a specific job that they would charge for Saturdays-Sundays from 10-9pm. How can I design the database so that I can keep track of different prices specified for different times? I don't have any standard times, but providers are free to choose whatever times they want.

I was thinking of the following structue:

price

```
provider_id
task_id
price
Mon
Tues
Wed 
Thurs
Friday
Saturday
Sunday
time_start
time_end
```

So if a task is on M-F, then a "1" will be entered for the columns Mon, Tues, ...., but a 0 will be entered for the columns Saturday, Sunday.

Comment: My first thought was horror you have seven separate columns vs say a single integer bitmask for the days but I guess as long as those are bit columns and not 32/64-bit integers that's probably not too bad. I might also separate the time data into a different table and reference that rather than include it in every record, but I doubt that'd make that much difference really either. This is part of the problem that people have to solve to implement recurring events in a calendar program so you might find inspiration looking for some of those.

Answer (score 3):

I would definitely separate this into several tables. You can do it all in one table, but ultimately, you will have more flexibility with more tables.

I would suggest the following structure:

ProviderTable

- id
- name
- anything else provider specific

TaskTable

- id
- name
- anything else task specific

TimeTable

- id
- dayOfWeek enum
- startTime
- endTime

PriceTable - to join together times and tasks

- id
- timeID
- taskID
- price

Job Table - to join together prices and providers

- id
- priceID
- providerID
- anything else job specific

This may seem like a lot of up front work, but later, as your database expands, you will be glad you did it.